# Can i get the downloaded M4A , MP3 file in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to download an audio file (M4A) and want to play it in my application, I did it successfully and moved it into a cache folder of the app. When I play it from the downloaded location it works fine only for once, when I close the application and reopen it, then iOS doesn't play the audio file on the same URL where I saved it before closing the application.  If I import the container through devices and simulator it shows that the file is present but the URL doesn't work. I'm not getting what's the issue. Kindly help

```swift
func getAudio () {
    if let audioUrl = songURL {

        // then lets create your document folder url
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        // lets create your destination file url
        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
        print(destinationUrl)

        // to check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")

            // if the file doesn't exist
        } else {
            // you can use NSURLSession.sharedSession to download the data asynchronously
            let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())

            let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: audioUrl)
            downloadTask.resume()
        }
    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("downloadLocation:", location)
    // create destination URL with the original pdf name
    guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url else { return }
    let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let destinationURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
    // delete original copy
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
    // copy from temp to Document
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
        self.songURL = destinationURL
        self.downloaded = true
    } catch let error {
        print("Copy Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

After downloading the file I get this url path: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDF4365C-59B4-4FCA-9E35-BF4FCD667134/Library/Caches/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3`

It works fine for one session of application (until the application is active).

Comment: Looking at your code you save it go the library directory (which im not sure you can) and then you try to fetch it from the documents directory.

Comment: i tried with same folder . it shows that i have file stored in documents folder but it don't play when i try to play it with avplayer .

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy the file directly to the `.libraryDirectory`, try for instance the documents directory instead, `.documentDirectory`

```
let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
```

Side note, do you really need to work with that `url` variable you have? Wouldn't it work to directly use `location`

```
let destinationURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(location.lastPathComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. I was trying to access the file with same URL. The thing is whenever app goes into background it reference changes. Whenever app come to foreground it gets new session ID/Number , so we first we need to get that session id then we must try to access the file by appending path. For that we can use fileManager.default.url(for: somedirectory , in .userdomainmask)[0]
 and then append the path with filename and extension